# Look at a row, determine if a field has a certain value, then count the number of specific values in a different field

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is a rather complex question to explain, I fear!

Here's the sample data I'm working with:

[image: Sample data]

What I'm trying to do is this:

---

Count the number of `Gold Gifted` students (i.e. where column `G` has a value of `Y`) that ALSO have a `KS4 TARGET` (column `I`) value of `A` or `A*`.

---

So, for instance, if the list has **5 Gold Gifted students**, but only **4** of those students have a **target grade of A* or A**, the value I would want displayed is **4**.

I'm not even sure where to start. I've tried the following formula but I'm not sure I'm even on the right lines:

`=SUM(('Student Breakdown'!$G$10:$G$272="Y")*('Student Breakdown'!$I$10:$I$272="A*")*('Student Breakdown'!$I$10:$I$272="A"))`

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the COUNTIFS function.

With your data layout, I think you would use

=COUNTIFS('Student Breakdown'!$G$10:$G$272, "Y", 'Student Breakdown'!$I$10:$I$272, "A*")

I'm not sure, but I think the fact that one of your target grades has an asterisk (A*) is working as a wild card in this instance.  You can test it out by changing one of the "A*" grades to "A+" and you should still get the proper totals.  An interesting side benefit!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend F106dart's answer but to generalise a little you can get an "OR" type effect with one condition in COUNTIFS like this

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(Range1,"x",Range2,{"a","b"}))`

[although you wouldn't do that with "A" and "A*" because the * acts as a wildcard as pointed out so you'd get double counting]

`COUNTIFS` is only available in Excel 2007 or later so for any version you can use `SUMPRODUCT` like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((Range1="x")*(Range2={"a","b"}))`

That latter version **will** work with "A" and "A*" because * is not treated as a wildcard in that formula.

Assumes Range1 and Range2 are `columns` of data

Comment: Nice trick with the array {"a", "b"}  !  I need to get better at using that technique.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works as well:

```
  =SUM(IF(G10:G272="Y",IF(I10:I272="A",1,0)))+SUM(IF(G10:G272="Y",IF(I10:I272="A*",1,0)))
```

It produces its result by using two passes at the conditional, one for A and one for A*.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts chuff but I haven't been able to get that to work - the result always appears as 0. I've used F106dart's answer instead.

Comment: It's an array formula that needs to be entered with CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER.  Sorry I failed to mention that!